# Javascript / jQuery Exec turns up Null

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, exec

How do I skip over this next line if it turns out to be null? Currently, it (sometimes) "breaks" and prevents the script from continuing.

**var title = (/(.*?)</title>/m).exec(response)[1];**

```
$.get(url, function(response){
    var title = (/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/m).exec(response)[1];
    if (title == null || title == undefined){
        return false;
    }
    var words = title.split(' ');
    $.each(words, function(index, value){
        $link.highlight(value + " ");
        $link.highlight(" " + value);
    });
 });
```

Comment: Use `===` to avoid type coercion. Or if you want type coercion, use `if (!title)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.get(url, function(response){
    var title = (/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/m).exec(response);
    if (!title || !title[1]){
        return false;
    }
    title=title[1];
    var words = title.split(' ');
    $.each(words, function(index, value){
        $link.highlight(value + " ");
        $link.highlight(" " + value);
    });
 });
```

You must check that title is not null **before** you get the result at index 1

Comment: `if (!title)` would be just fine too, since exec will either return a match or `null`.

Comment: You must check that title`s length is greater than 1

Comment: @chapluck: he could just change it to `if (!title || !title[1])` if he wanted to return on an empty title string (`<title></title>`)